# Laravel 4 - Access Auth Class in Validation Class

Tags: php, authentication, namespaces, laravel-4

I want to access the Auth Class within my ValidatorService Class.

```
namespace Services\Validators\User;

use \Services\Validators\Validator;

use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Edit extends Validator {

    public static $rules = [
        'email' => 'required|unique:users,email,'.Auth::user()->id
    ];
}
```

I tried to use the `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth` Namespace, but laravel throws an Exception.

Error: `syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ']'`

[image]

Laravel only throws the exception, when I try to use Auth::user()->id.
If I remove Auth::user()->id and add a number, for example 1, it works.

I also tried to implement the `Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface` but it is not working.

How can I use the Auth Class in my ValidatorService Class?

**EDIT:** Problem solved -> Scroll down.

Comment: what are you trying to use the logged in users id for?

Comment: For the unique rule (as you can see above :-) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution:

> You cannot use functions or variables when setting a variable on a
>   class.

Thanks to AndreasLutro on http://laravel.io/irc

So I removed the class variable and added a method.
Now everythings works fine.

Code:

```
class Edit extends Validator{

    public static function rules(){

        return array(

            'email' => 'required|unique:users,email,'.Auth::user()->id

        );
    }
}
```

Cheers, Steven.

Answer (score 1):

Try to surround the `'required|unique:users,email,'.Auth::user()->id`
part with `(` and `)` so that it looks like this:

```
public static $rules = [
    'email' => ('required|unique:users,email,' . Auth::user()->id)
];
```