# laravel validation own rule with Input::get Parameter in rule

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I want add an own rule that will check if my "active" flag is allowed to set.
I only want set this flag when this query get no result:

```
$playlist = Playlist::whereRaspberryId($raspberry_id)->whereActive(1)->first();
```

my validator rule is so far:

```
Validator::extend('onlyOneActive', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
    {
        $playlist = Playlist::whereRaspberryId($parameters['raspberry_id'])->whereActive(1)->first();
        if($playlist) {
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    });
```

My problem is the parameter. This is a value from another field in my form.
But how I get it?

This is my $rules array:

```
# Validate Rules
    private static $rules = array(
        'name' => 'required',
        'active' => 'onlyOneActive:raspberry_id',
    );
```

The problem:
In my own rule the parameter is only this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => raspberry_id
)
```

This is logical. But I want the raspberry_id from my form, not the string..
How get I the id?

This doesn't work:

```
# Validate Rules
    private static $rules = array(
        'name' => 'required',
        'active' => 'onlyOneActive:'.Input::get('raspberry_id'),
    );
```

got error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ')'
```

Anyone an idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it..
I use Input::get('raspberry_id) directly in my rule.
Is this a bad solution?

```
Validator::extend('onlyOneActive', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
    {
        $playlist = Playlist::whereRaspberryId(Input::get('raspberry_id'))->whereActive(1)->first();
        if($playlist) {
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem, the reason is

> You cannot use functions or variables when setting a variable on a class.

I think solution is not really good cause input name `"raspberry_id"`
 can be different in other place where you would use this rule.
A bit better would be this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21208740/4581725.
Or you can not define `$rules` in class and define it in place in code where you use validation function.